# XML schema "sequence" or "any" query in tsql

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, xsd

My department is in a transitional phase switching from "sequence" XML schema data to "any".  In this phase, I'm looking for a possible query into the "`sys`" tables to find that element.  I've looked in `sys.xml_schema_elements`, `sys.xml_schema_collections`.  I've found a lot of meta data in SQL Server's XML views, but not the text, "sequence" or "any".

Is it under different verbage, am I looking in the wrong place, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [sys.xml_schema_model_groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179852.aspx) and the field `compositor`.

```
Compositor kind of group: 
A = XSD <all> Group 
C = XSD <choice> Group
S = XSD <sequence> Group
```